# OfficeJS- Open angular route on dialog

Tags: office-js, add-in, cpu-word

I am using OfficeJS API to create word add-in. In that i want to open dialog when click on ribbon button and load a angular route on that dialog. I did it using officeJs API:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, {height: 30, width: 20});
```

So using that API i am able to load my angular component on dialog.  Now from dialog i want to communicate with document. So i have written some code below

```
await Word.run(async (context) => {

   var body = context.document.body;
   var bodyOOXML = body.getOoxml();
   await context.sync();

})
```

When await context.sync(); line is esecuted i get 'Access Denied at anonymous function' error. I'm not able to find the cause of this error. If anyone know the solution for this error please help.  Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks In advance.

Pooja.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Office JavaScript APIs are not usable in the dialog. You can only use `isSetSupported` and `messageParent`. If you want to give users the experience of interacting with the document from the dialog, you must have the interaction functions in the parent page, which in your case would be the function file where you call `displayDialogAsync`. When the user takes an action (such as clicking a button) in the dialog, the handler for the event calls `messageParent` and sends information about what action was taken (such as, button 1 was clicked) to the parent. In the parent page, the handler for DialogMessageReceived carries out the desired action on the document.

Comment: I want to communicate with document from the init method of angular component after the route url is loaded.

Comment: We don't recommend that you pass a route to the dialog. See [Best practices for using the Office dialog API in an SPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-best-practices#best-practices-for-using-the-office-dialog-api-in-an-spa).